# Haskell - Import text file to list type

Tags: haskell, file-io

I am beginner in haskell. I have a `.txt` file in the following format:

```
Company A, 100, 1000
```

I need to import each row to a list of one type:

```
type GerCred = [(String, Int, Int)]
```

How do I do that?

**Update**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
type GerCred = [(String,Int,Int)]
type GerCarb = [(String,Int)]

readGerCredList :: File -> IO GerCred
readGerCredList fname = do contents <- readFile fname return(read contents)
```

Comment: I updated my original post with what i have so far, thx

Comment: You should check out `words`, `lines`, and `read`.

Comment: You might consider a CSV library like `cassava`

Answer (score 3):

Break the problem down into bits.

First, figure out how to read the file into a single big string (hint, look for something that returns "IO String")

Then figure out how to take that string and split it into lines (hint: lines).

Then figure out how to take each line and split it into fields (hint: span, stripPrefix)

Then figure out how to convert each field into the type you need (hint: read).

Then figure out how to put it all together (hint: map)

Don't forget that a String is just a [Char].

Paul.

Comment: Yes, and let me add:  Paul's broken the problem down into 5 bits; you don't have to work on them in sequential order.  I'd suggest starting with #3, "take each line and split into fields".  You can do this by making a temporary definition:
<pre>
    t = "Company A, 100, 1000"
    type GerCred = [(String, Int, Int)]
    f :: String -> GerCred
    f = undefined  -- replace this with your version
</pre>